# How to reflect scala class instance?

Tags: scala, reflection

Assuming the following code:

```
package my.package

case class ExampleCaseClass(s: String, i: Int, ...)
object ExampleCaseClass {
  val instance = ExampleCaseClass("number", 5, ...)
}
```

how can I extract class info and data using Scala reflection if the only reference is a string, say `my.package.ExampleCaseClass.instance` or something along these lines?

In other words, I want to have a function `getInfo: String => String` which does, say, the following:

```
getInfo("my.package.ExampleCaseClass.instance") =
  "ExampleCaseClass ( s: number, i: 5, ... )"
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses `Java Class.forName`:

```
def getInfo(className: String = "finnova.bpf.report.entity.DocumentBarcode") = { 
  val fields =
  Class.forName(className).getDeclaredFields
    .map(f => s"${f.getName}: ${f.getType.getSimpleName}")
    .mkString("(", ", ", ")")
  s"$className$fields"
}
```

This uses `scala.reflect`

```
import scala.reflect._

def getInfo(className: String = "finnova.bpf.report.entity.DocumentBarcode") = { 
  val classSymbol = runtime.currentMirror.classSymbol(Class.forName(className))
  val primCtor = classSymbol.info.decls.find(m => m.isMethod && m.asMethod.isPrimaryConstructor).get
  val fields = primCtor.typeSignature.paramLists.head
  .map(f => s"${f.name}: ${f.info.resultType}").mkString("(", ", ",")")

  s"$className$fields"
}
```

This is a bit more involved, but you get much more information. Here is a nice blog that gets you started: https://medium.com/@giposse/scala-reflection-d835832ed13a